# Disintegration of deuteron into n & p by a gamma ray - energy considerations

Tags: nuclear-physics, gamma-rays

I was working through a problem that has a Deuteron of mass $M$ and binding energy $B$ disintegrated by a $\gamma$-ray of energy $E_\gamma$ into a neutron and proton. It proceeds to ask to find the minimum value of $E_\gamma -B$ for which this reaction occurs.
$$ D + \gamma  \rightarrow p + n $$
The solution outlined in the text is as thus

$$ (E_\gamma + Mc^2)^2 - E_\gamma^2  = (m_n + m_p)^2c^4, \tag A$$
$$ 2E_\gamma Mc^2 = [(m_n+m_p)^2 - M^2]c^4 = (B+ 2Mc^2)B,$$
Finally
$$\\ E_\gamma - B = \frac{B^2}{2Mc^2}$$

I can understand that the minimum value is when the proton and neutron are stationary after the split up. So I'm guessing the energy of $E_\gamma$ = $(m_n +m_p)c^2$, which is the rest mass.

I'm not so interested in the final answer, but I was wondering how did they arrive at the first equation? And to disintegrate a Deuteron nucleus, wouldn't I just have to match the $\gamma$ energy to the binding energy $B$? Why do we still consider $E_\gamma - B$?

Can someone shed some light on this issue.

Comment: Your second line of mathematics (which I think is what you mean by "the first equation," so I labeled it (A) to be unambiguous) is not dimensionally consistent.  Should the first term also be squared?

Comment: Your guess gives an energy to the gamma that is the energy of the neutron and the proton. A huge energy. The binding energy is the difference between the sum of the energyof the masses of a neutron+proton minus that of the deuteron, I suppose M in your formulas. The gamma has to overcome the binding energy.

Comment: Can you give the name of the book where you found this question?

Comment: This is my favorite reaction.

Comment: @annav Note that if you always needed the final state rest mass to overcome binding energy, it would be really hard to open a bottle of soda pop.

Comment: I might have read the question wrong, but do you know what an inner product is?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the minimum energy of the gamma photon is not simply equal to the binding energy is- momentum conservation. Any incoming photon having energy equal to the binding energy will also have some momentum, while if you just fulfill the binding energy requirement, you will get two stationary proton and neutron with no momentum as the end product. Hence, one needs something more than just the binding energy.

In order to get the first equation, you have to make some simplifying assumptions. Assume that the non zero momentum of the neutron and the proton produced in the end are equal and along the same direction (approximately of course). Also, assume that the masses of the neutron and proton are equal. Then apply energy and momentum conservation, and you will get the first equation.